# Runge's phenomen: interpolation error using Chebyshev nodes oscillates

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

We're trying to approximate the Runge function $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+25x^2}$ using Chebyshev nodes. When calculating the interpolation error, using different degrees ranging from 0 to 50, we get the following plot:

[image]

The blue dots are the interpolation errors using Chebyshev points for increasing degrees. We use a logaritmic scale for the vertical axis. As you can clearly see, they oscillate quite a bit. This oscillating seems to depend on the degree: if it's even, the errors are a bit lower.

Using equidistant points, we get exactly the same but if the degree is even, the errors are a bit higher.

What is a possible explanation for this phenomenon?

Thanks!

Comment: See my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775405/fx-1-1x2-lagrange-polynomials-do-not-always-converge-why/807784#807784 for an elementary proof that equispaced points don't converge. You should be able to extract the precise error behavior from that answer.