# Proof that the Runge Phenomenon occurs

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, interpolation, approximation-theory

Is there such a proof that states that the Runge Phenomena will always occur when interpolating with higher order polynomials or is this just observed empirically?

Comment: the reason is given right [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon#Reason)

Answer (score 3):

The Runge Phenomenon does not always occur. You can interpolate, say, $f(x)=  e^x$  using equally spaced nodes on any interval $[a,b]$, and the interpolating polynomials will converge to $f$ uniformly.  (The same holds for any function whose Taylor series has infinite radius of convergence.)

When the Runge phenomenon does occur, it is a lot easier to observe empirically than to write down a rigorous proof that it happens. This is why the  textbooks on numerical analysis tend to do the former and not the latter.

For the classical example of intepolating $f(x)=1/(1+x^2)$ on $[-5,5]$ by equally spaced nodes, David Speyer [posted a complete proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/807784) of divergence at $x=4$.

Answer (score 1):

Runge Phenomena doesn't occur for all functions. For a detailed analysis on polynomial interpolation at equidistant points you can have a look [here](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Epperson329-341.pdf)

Comment: The requested page "/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Epperson329-341.pdf." could not be found.

Comment: @NormalHuman There's a dot at the end. Here's the link http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Epperson329-341.pdf